# Deleting a property from an entity

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I've been using code like this for awhile to delete a property from an entity:

```
for e in entities:
    if hasattr(e, attr):
        delattr(e, attr)
ndp.put_multi(entities)
```

When I have done this in the past, the properties were immediately removed from the datastore viewer.

I did this yesterday, but the datastore viewer still shows the deleted properties as `<null>` for all the entities.

Have there been any changes to the app engine datastore that changes the process for removing a property from an entity?

UPDATE:

The old datastore viewer shows the deleted properties (at appengine.google.com) but the new datastore viewer (at console.developers.google.com) does not.  I still use the old datastore viewer because the new one does not truncate the values of long properties which makes it unusable for me.

Comment: You need to clarify a bit. You seem to switch from "Property" to "entity" freely in here, and it makes for a confusing reading. If I understood correctly, it used to not show the deleted property, and now it shows "null"? Or is it that the new console doesn't update as quick? If it's the later, then it's possible that it's just some consistency issue.

Comment: @Patrice, sorry about that.  Just edited to correctly use property and entity.  The old datastore used to not show the deleted property, and now it shows it as <null>.  The new datastore does not show the deleted properties.

Comment: Cool. I have a better grasp of what you're asking about now. But if this is a feature you would like to see back in the new console, the issue tracker would be a better place for this:https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list.

Comment: @Patrice, in my view the new console is working correctly.  The old console used to work correctly but now it is hanging on to deleted properties.  No point in doing a feature request for the old console. :)

Comment: Totally fair :). In this case, I'm not sure what is expected of this stack post. Something changed, yes, but I don't think we'll be able to know why or how. Anyway with the old console going away over time, this won't stay an issue.